unwrap or evalulate to false in rust
I have encountered several cases similar this:
if let Some(x) = formula_chars.peek() {
    if x.is_lowercase() {
        todo!()
    }
}

where I would like an expression to evaluate to false if an Option is None or some operation on the Some variant, (in this case is_lowercase() ) returns false. However, the only way I've found to do this is using nested if statements as shown above. Is there some way to do this with a single expression? preferably something along the lines of the code below:
note: code below doesn't work it is just to illustrate the desired behavior
if formula_chars.peek().unwrap_or(false).is_lowercase() {
    todo!()
}

P.S. in this specific case I know I could just unwrap_or to a non-lowercase character e.g.
if formula_chars.peek().unwrap_or('_').is_lowercase() {
    todo!()
}

but I'm looking for a more general (and preferably less bodge-y) solution

Or more classically map().unwrap_or(), the transformation operation needs to be applied before the unwrapping.

@Masklinn Thanks for the answer, that works great though provided you're on a recent version of rust (it was added in 1.70) I do prefer @eggyal's suggestion of is_some_and from a readability perspective.

I think you're confused, is_some_and was added in 1.70, map and unwrap_or have been here since 1.0

@Masklinn Not sure if my previous comment was poorly worded but that is what I was saying.

You can use Option::is_some_and:
if formula_chars.peek().is_some_and(|x| x.is_lowercase()) {
    todo!()
}

Instead of defining a lambda that immediately delegates to another function, I find it slightly more ergonomic to pass the delegated function as a path expression:
if formula_chars.peek().is_some_and(char::is_lowercase) {
    todo!()
}

However, the method call expression used in the lambda performs auto-deref on the receiver x (if necessary) but this doesn't happen if the function is passed as a path expression.  Therefore, since in this case char::is_lowercase takes a char not &char, if you have an Option<&char> you could first call Option::copied:
if formula_chars.peek().copied().is_some_and(char::is_lowercase) {
    todo!()
}

It's just personal taste.  YMMV.

Some other options:

map_or():
if formula_chars.peek().map_or(false, |c| c.is_lowercase())


map() then unwrap_or(), some people prefer this to map_or():
if formula_chars.peek().map(|c| c.is_lowercase()).unwrap_or(false)


Or, the most flexible (but pretty unreadable), a match:
if match formula_chars.peek() {
    Some(c) if c.is_lowercase() => true,
    _ => false,
} {
    // ...
}


An alternative match:
if match formula_chars.peek() {
    Some(c) => c.is_lowercase(),
    None => false,
} {
    // ...
}



You should probably prefer is_some_and(), it is the cleanest and most specific combinator, but those can be useful in other scenarios.
